# How to use a const static member variable outside of its class in C++

Tags: c++, static, constants

```
struct Test
{
    const static int VALUE = 10;
    int a;
    int b;
}

class Foo
{
public:
    const Test& GetTest() { return t; }
private:
    Test t;
}

class Bar
{
public:
    void bar() 
    {
        Foo foo;
        int value = foo.GetTest().VALUE; // link error in linux gcc version 4.4.7 (saids undefine reference) and ok in vs2015
        int value = Test::VALUE; // both ok
    }
}
```

so, what is the reference say about this case ? I feel like the second way to use it is the correct way,  but I can't quite argue the first way to be wrong...
please help, thanks a lot...

Comment: Please post the actual code that you tried to compile. What you have instead posted will first give an error on the line `class Foo` because it is a syntax error to have that appear immediately after the closing brace of a struct definition. Also there is no `main()` function, so you should get a link error about missing `main` instead of the actual link error you reported.

Comment: There's also the error from having two definitions of `value` in the same scope. These things might seem irrelevant, but too often we see code the poster thinks will replicate their problem, but actually doesn't, so it's important that you've checked the result of exactly what you paste here.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting the linker error is  your compiler thinks `TEST::VALUE` is used by reference.

That is my non-standardese speak for what the standard calls *odr-used*. If the compiler can deduce that it needs to access a variable by its address, then it is used by reference. Those variables must be defined in such a way that their addresses can be used at run time to access the variables.

In the expression `foo.GetTest().VALUE;`, `TEST::VALUE` is *odr-used*.

An *odr-used* variable must be defined properly. In your case, you can use:

```
struct Test
{
    const static int VALUE = 10;
    int a;
    int b;
}

const int Test::VALUE;
```

**Update**

Your version of g++ appears to be buggy. I don't see the linker error using g++ 5.4.0 on my desktop. I don't see the linker error using g++ 6.0.3 at [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/yt4HD9).

Comment: What does "used by reference" mean?

Comment: @M.M are you asking me to elaborate on that point in my answer?

Comment: Yeah, or in comments.

Comment: I don't see how the expression `foo.GetTest().VALUE` would require the address of VALUE.  Even though some sort of "referencing" is involved in `foo.GetTest()`, that's all irrelevant to `VALUE` which can only ever be one thing

Comment: @M.M, thanks for not being satisfied with my answer :)